# How to use Rotativa to shrink content down to a single PDF page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, rotativa

Using Rotativa in an ASP.NET project and I'm wondering if there is a way to programmatically tell it to shrink the HTML content used to generate the PDF into a **single** landscape-orientated page?

My current code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PrintStratgicMap(int employeeId, string slug, string fiscalYear)
{
     return new ActionAsPdf("Goals", new { employeeId = employeeId, slug = slug, fiscalYear = fiscalYear }) 
     { FileName = "strategic_map.pdf", 
       FormsAuthenticationCookieName = ".auth", 
       CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type", 
       PageOrientation=Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `page-break-inside: avoid;` combined with dynamically changing changing your font size?